# Trigger IFTTT event when GCalendar event is X days from due or when a notification is triggered

Tags: automation, calendar, google-calendar-api, ifttt

I'd like IFTTT to send notifications to other apps when a GCalendar event is close to due date.

The best way would be IFTTT to notice it from due date, so that all events are automatically in place, but it can also be an event notification then I add notification to all events. But I can't find how to trigger any of those on IFTTT.

As alternative, I'll thank any suggestion of another calendar tool that integrates with IFTTT, I searched and found only Apple calendar.